# Find Determinant of A

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I've tried creating a triangular matrix, tried row reducing but can't figure it out as I keep on having c-unknown in my answer. How would I do this? [image]

Comment: Use the zeros in the first column.

Comment: It seems straight forward to "triangularize" $A$. What's the problem?

Comment: I cant get all the terms to be zero lower the diagonal

Comment: The answer to part (a) is *supposed* to have $c$ in it, but from the phrasing of your question it sounds like you don't believe this to be acceptable.  Since $A$ itself depends on $c$, so there's no reason to expect that $\det(A)$ does not.

Comment: @ErickWong really? I thought there would be a way to create a lower/upper triangular matrix and get a constant answer for det(A)

Comment: @Mac Just try calculating $\det(A)$ for two different values of $c$, say $0$ and $1$.  You'll find you get two different determinants, thus it cannot possibly be constant.  Having an answer that depends on $c$ is not a weakness: it is in fact a prediction of the precise value of $\det(A)$ no matter $c$ is chosen to be!

Comment: @ErickWong, Thanks your comments were extremely helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

Expanding along column 1 or row 4 (since they each have two zeros), we arrive at:

$$\det A = -20 - 5 c$$

Can you take it from here?

What part does this determinant play in the inverse of a matrix? Recall that

$$A^{-1} = \dfrac{1}{\det A} adj(A)$$

What does that mean for the value of $c$?

Comment: If I expand along column 1 or row 4, I will have be left with a constant c just like you have shown. How does that help me?

Comment: a would not able to be 0

Comment: I thought there would be away to calculate det(A) using some sort of operation (i.e creating a upper/lower triangular matrix) that would enable me to get a constant answer for det(A). So for the second part I can say the determinant is invertible for all values of c other than -4?

Comment: Bingo!!! So **every** other value is legal for $c$. Regards

Comment: thanks for the help! I just updated my earlier comment!